# Nginx rewrite prevent redirection

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am trying to make a url rewrite as following:

```
 location /statics/ {
    alias /var/project/statics/;
 }
 location /statics/cache {
    rewrite /statics/cache/(.*?)/(.*)$ http://$host/statics/$2 last;
 }
```

Where URL would be as:
http://ANY-DOMAIN.com/statics/cache/1.2.5/file/path/file.js
The original file is:
http://ANY-DOMAIN.com/statics/file/path/file.js

The problem here is: 
URL is redirecting (changing URL) to original file. I want to prevent the redirection.

Current status:
Redirects to original URL

Comment: Remove host part from rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by Changing the Mask URL as following:

new url: http://ANY-DOMAIN.com/cdn/cache/1.2.5/file/path/file.js
instead of http://ANY-DOMAIN.com/statics/cache/1.2.5/file/path/file.js

And the rewrite rule to be as:

```
location /cdn/cache {
    rewrite /cdn/cache/(.*?)/(.*)$ /statics/$2 last;
}
```